# Conditionally add properties to task/module in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm developing a role where I want to launch a docker container, among the tasks in my role I have one using the `docker_container` module to do that:

```
- name: Launch docker container
  docker_container:
    name: abc
    ...
```

This works fine but now I want to have a variable that will define whether this container needs to be attached to a particular docker network.
If I require it is fine:

```
- name: Launch docker container
  docker_container:
    name: abc
    networks:
      - name: '{{ network_name_var}}'
        ...
```

But I want to allow the users to not define it, in which case no `networks: ...` property should be added.
I have found no easy way of achieving this, is there one?

Semantically I want something like this:

```
- name: Launch docker container
  docker_container:
    name: abc
{% if network_name_var is defined %}
    networks:
      - name: '{{ network_name_var}}'
        ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible scenario you can use. The key points:

- We keep your single `network_name_var` that is exposed to your user. I took for granted that this var could be either undefined, or empty.
- We define the full network list definition dynamically if the var has a value set. This list stays unset otherwise.
- We use the [`omit` place holder](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters) to not define any networks in the module if need be.

```
- name: demo playbook for omit
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: set the list of networks for our container
      # don't define anywhere else. it should only exist
      # if network_name_var is set
      set_fact:
        my_networks:
          - name: '{{ network_name_var }}'
      when: network_name_var | default('') | length > 0

    - name: make sure container is started
      docker_container:
        name: abc
        networks: "{{ my_networks | default(omit) }}"
```

Comment: The most important part of the answer is `"default(omit)"`